# how to make buttons with different text length to fit in a same row in android

Tags: android, android-layout, resize, android-button

[image]

this is what I had to design, and I designed it the above image is the actual screenshot of the running app.

I used 15 buttons for it and aligned 3 buttons to each other for a signal row and it came out perfectly **Util i run the app on other phone which have small screen**

[image]

and this is what I get, now I didn't came directly here to ask this question I have been trying to solve it from last 14 hours but nothing is working

here is my code for the bottomSheetView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout11"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_35sdp"
        android:background="@drawable/goal_bottom_sheet_header_bg"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_filter_tittle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
            android:text="Filter by Log"
            android:textColor="@color/goal_picker_tittle"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_14ssp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_cancel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
            android:text="✕"
            android:textColor="@color/goal_picker_measurement"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_11ssp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/filter_picker_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_12sdp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_12sdp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_8sdp"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_8sdp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout11">

<!--        first row of buttons-->

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/glucose_btn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Glucose"
            android:textColor="@color/black_color1"
            android:backgroundTint="#eeffffff"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_glucose_vector_icon_white_color"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/sleep_btn"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sleep_btn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:textColor="@color/black_color1"
            android:backgroundTint="#eeffffff"
            android:text="Sleep"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_sleep_vector_icon_white_color"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/medicine_btn"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/glucose_btn"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/medicine_btn"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:textColor="@color/black_color1"
            android:backgroundTint="#eeffffff"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Medicine"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_medicien_vector_icon_white_color"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/sleep_btn"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

        <!-- second row of buttond -->

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bp_btn"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:textColor="@color/black_color1"
            android:backgroundTint="#eeffffff"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="BP"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_bp_vector_icon_white_color"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/weight_btn"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/glucose_btn"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/weight_btn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:textColor="@color/black_color1"
            android:backgroundTint="#eeffffff"
            android:text="Weight"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_weight_vector_icon_white_color"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/meals_btn"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/bp_btn"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/glucose_btn"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/meals_btn"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:textColor="@color/black_color1"
            android:backgroundTint="#eeffffff"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Meals"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_meals_vector_icon_white_color"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/weight_btn"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/glucose_btn"/>

        <!-- thrid row of buttons -->

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/activity_btn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/black_color1"
            android:backgroundTint="#eeffffff"
            android:text="Activity"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_activity_vector_icon_white_color"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/vitals_btn"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/bp_btn"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/vitals_btn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:textColor="@color/black_color1"
            android:backgroundTint="#eeffffff"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:text="Vitals"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_vitals_vector_icon_white_color"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/acr_btn"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/activity_btn"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/bp_btn"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/acr_btn"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:textColor="@color/black_color1"
            android:backgroundTint="#eeffffff"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="ACR"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_acr_vector_icon_white_color"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/vitals_btn"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/bp_btn"/>

        <!-- forth row of buttons -->

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/heatrate_btn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:textColor="@color/black_color1"
            android:backgroundTint="#eeffffff"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Heart Rate"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_heartrate_vector_icon_white_color"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/spo2_btn"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/activity_btn"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/spo2_btn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:textColor="@color/black_color1"
            android:backgroundTint="#eeffffff"
            android:text="Spo2"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_spo2_vector_icon_white_color"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/fluid_intake_btn"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/heatrate_btn"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/activity_btn"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/fluid_intake_btn"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/black_color1"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:backgroundTint="#eeffffff"
            android:text="Fluid"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_fluid_vector_icon_white_color"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/spo2_btn"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/activity_btn"/>


        <!-- fifth button row -->

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/temp_btn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:textColor="@color/black_color1"
            android:backgroundTint="#eeffffff"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Tempature"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_temp_vector_icon_white_color"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/scr_btn"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/heatrate_btn"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/scr_btn"
            android:textColor="@color/black_color1"
            android:backgroundTint="#eeffffff"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:text="SCR"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_scr_vector_icon_white_color"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/urine_btn"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/temp_btn"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/heatrate_btn"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/urine_btn"
            android:textColor="@color/black_color1"
            android:backgroundTint="#eeffffff"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:text="Urine"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_urine_vector_icon_white_color"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/scr_btn"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/heatrate_btn"/>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_70sdp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/urine_btn"
            />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:id="@+id/horizontalLine"
        android:background="@color/gray"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/filter_picker_view"/>

    <TextView
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/_7sdp"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_7sdp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_15ssp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Clear All"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/tv_clearAll"
        android:background="#F7F7F7"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/horizontalLine"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/verticalLine"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/verticalLine"
        android:layout_width="0.5dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/gray"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/tv_apply"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/tv_clearAll"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/horizontalLine"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/tv_apply"
        />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Apply"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_15ssp"
        android:textColor="@color/splash_title"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/_7sdp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_7sdp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
        android:background="#F7F7F7"
        android:id="@+id/tv_apply"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/horizontalLine"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/verticalLine"/>



</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the size of the screen using `DisplayMetrics`, then set the font size, and if required, the width of the tabs, programmatically as per the screen size. This will work in almost all the cases.

Comment: is there any other way through xml

Comment: I'm afraid not. That is the problem with xml, which is why we are shifting to declarative UI as Compose. Anyway, programmatically determining the smallest font size that fits and assigning that to all the other views is by far the best I could think

Comment: thanks dude, but i did with the XML see my answer

Answer (score 0):

so here is the new XML code, which worked
so basically in a row (which contains 3 buttons) I set the width to 0dp for those buttons those texts was small and set wrap_containt to those whose text was long, and also decreased the font size by 3dps and now its looking the same on all the phones

here is the new code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout11"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_35sdp"
        android:background="@drawable/goal_bottom_sheet_header_bg"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_filter_tittle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
            android:text="Filter by Log"
            android:textColor="@color/goal_picker_tittle"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_14ssp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_cancel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
            android:text="✕"
            android:textColor="@color/goal_picker_measurement"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_11ssp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/filter_picker_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_12sdp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_12sdp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_8sdp"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_8sdp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout11">
<!--        first row of buttons-->

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/glucose_btn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Glucose"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_9ssp"
            android:textColor="@color/black_color1"
            android:backgroundTint="#eeffffff"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_glucose_vector_icon_white_color"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/sleep_btn"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sleep_btn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="@color/black_color1"
            android:backgroundTint="#eeffffff"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_9ssp"
            android:text="Sleep"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_sleep_vector_icon_white_color"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/medicine_btn"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/glucose_btn"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/medicine_btn"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/black_color1"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_9ssp"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:backgroundTint="#eeffffff"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Medicine"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_medicien_vector_icon_white_color"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/sleep_btn"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
        <!-- second row of buttond -->
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bp_btn"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:textColor="@color/black_color1"
            android:backgroundTint="#eeffffff"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_9ssp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="BP"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_bp_vector_icon_white_color"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/weight_btn"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/glucose_btn"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/weight_btn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:textColor="@color/black_color1"
            android:backgroundTint="#eeffffff"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_9ssp"
            android:text="Weight"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_weight_vector_icon_white_color"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/meals_btn"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/bp_btn"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/glucose_btn"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/meals_btn"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:textColor="@color/black_color1"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:backgroundTint="#eeffffff"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_9ssp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Meals"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_meals_vector_icon_white_color"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/weight_btn"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/glucose_btn"/>
        <!-- thrid row of buttons -->

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/activity_btn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/black_color1"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_9ssp"
            android:backgroundTint="#eeffffff"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="Activity"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_activity_vector_icon_white_color"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/vitals_btn"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/bp_btn"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/vitals_btn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/black_color1"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_9ssp"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:backgroundTint="#eeffffff"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:text="Vitals"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_vitals_vector_icon_white_color"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/acr_btn"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/activity_btn"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/bp_btn"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/acr_btn"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:textColor="@color/black_color1"
            android:backgroundTint="#eeffffff"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_9ssp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="ACR"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_acr_vector_icon_white_color"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/vitals_btn"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/bp_btn"/>
        <!-- forth row of buttons -->

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/heatrate_btn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/black_color1"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_9ssp"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:backgroundTint="#eeffffff"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Heart Rate"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_heartrate_vector_icon_white_color"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/spo2_btn"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/activity_btn"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/spo2_btn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="@color/black_color1"
            android:backgroundTint="#eeffffff"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_9ssp"
            android:text="Spo2"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_spo2_vector_icon_white_color"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/fluid_intake_btn"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/heatrate_btn"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/activity_btn"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/fluid_intake_btn"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/black_color1"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:backgroundTint="#eeffffff"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_9ssp"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="Fluid"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_fluid_vector_icon_white_color"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/spo2_btn"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/activity_btn"/>
        <!-- fifth button row -->

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/temp_btn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/black_color1"
            android:backgroundTint="#eeffffff"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_9ssp"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="Tempature"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_temp_vector_icon_white_color"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/scr_btn"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/heatrate_btn"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/scr_btn"
            android:textColor="@color/black_color1"
            android:backgroundTint="#eeffffff"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_9ssp"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:text="SCR"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_scr_vector_icon_white_color"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/urine_btn"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/temp_btn"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/heatrate_btn"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/urine_btn"
            android:textColor="@color/black_color1"
            android:backgroundTint="#eeffffff"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_9ssp"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:text="Urine"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_urine_vector_icon_white_color"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/scr_btn"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/heatrate_btn"/>
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_70sdp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/urine_btn"
            />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:id="@+id/horizontalLine"
        android:background="@color/gray"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/filter_picker_view"/>
    <TextView
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/_7sdp"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_7sdp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_15ssp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Clear All"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/tv_clearAll"
        android:background="#F7F7F7"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/horizontalLine"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/verticalLine"/>
    <View
        android:id="@+id/verticalLine"
        android:layout_width="0.5dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/gray"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/tv_apply"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/tv_clearAll"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/horizontalLine"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/tv_apply"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Apply"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_15ssp"
        android:textColor="@color/splash_title"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/_7sdp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_7sdp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
        android:background="#F7F7F7"
        android:id="@+id/tv_apply"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/horizontalLine"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/verticalLine"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```